# How do I create a real database for a form?

Tags: html

So im brand new to web design (ive spent about 7 hours in HTML so far and i love it)

However, if I want my clicks to actually reach a database instead of theoretically like in how we practice it - how do I attach a real link to <form action="enter your real database url here"?

Comment: HTML won't post data to a database. You are looking for a back end programming language such as PHP.  This is a good place to start: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: With something like Firebase you can connect to it directly using JavaScript, but I don't think there's any way to do it with plain HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send your form data from the form to a php file on your server, like this: `<form action="../yourdirectory/receive_formdata.php">` and then in that php file process the form data into variables that you can then either put into the database or send by email to the site owner, or similar.

The php file will connect to a database and run an INSERT operation (if it is a SQL type db) on that database where the database table will be populated with a row of fields from the FORM data that was submitted.

A typical operation in the php file could look like this, to extract each form field and store it in memory as a variable:

```
    $fields = [
        'category' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'message' => '',
        'etc' => '',
    ];

    // Crude validation of input, but remember to strip tags too
    $fields_valid = true;
    foreach( $fields as $field=>$value ){
        if( array_key_exists( $field, $_REQUEST ) && !empty( $_REQUEST[$field] )) {
            // trim will work nicely with multi-byte values
            $fields[$field] = trim($_REQUEST[$field]);
        } else {
            $fields_valid = false;
        }
    }
```

Then run the actual input to database operation, along these lines:

```
function insertFields($category, $email, $message, $etc) {

  $connection = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO `messages_from_web`
    (`category`, `email`, `message`, `etc`)
    VALUES (:category, :email, :message)");

  $connection->bindParam(":category", $category);
  $connection->bindParam(":email", $email);
  $connection->bindParam(":message", $message);
  $connection->bindParam(":etc", $etc);
  $connection->execute();
}
```

Loosely explained, but hope you get some material to investigate further :)

Comment: so much of that is above me! thank you! ill keep learning! great answer!